# Set styles for dynamically added html code in email template

Tags: php, html, css, email, email-templates

I am currently working on a responsive email template and facing an issue how to style dynamically added html code.

As most of the email client not supported with embedded CSS I added inline styles, since the part of the template loading dynamically I can't add inline styles for that part.

Example : I need to load following html sample code dynamically to my email template.

```
<p>bla bla bla .....</p>
<a href=""><img src="" class="" /></a>
<p>bla bla bla .....</p>
```

In this example how should set a `max-width` for the `img` element the way it should work for most of the email clients?

Please note that I am using `PHP` as programming language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to make changes in the html code as bellow,

```
function add_inline_styles($string){
    $string = str_get_html($string);
    foreach($string->find('img') as $key => $img_tags) {
        $img_tags->setAttribute("style", max-width: 570px;");
    }
    return $string;
}
```

In order to use dom parser you should include [simple_html_dom.php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) and for more information please follow the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Answer (score 0):

if you can set `class` or `src`, you may do:

```
 $class='something';

 $class= $class. '"' . ' style="max-wdth:100px;';
```

then you will have:

```
 <img src="" class="something" style="max-wdth:100px;" />
```

Comment: as I mention in the question I can't use inline styles for this part

Comment: @JanithChinthana Why can't you?

Comment: the part of html code which I mention in the question is  loading dynamically,  so the html code loading as it is. I can't change anything over there as you suggest

Comment: @JanithChinthana since you have not said what you **are**  able to do, it's very difficult to guess a proper solution